# what is the best way to partition /tmp and /var/log in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: partitioning, mount, amazon-ec2, aws

Using aws ec2 ubuntu 18.04 OS.

1. Need to perform CIS hardening task for file system where we need to partition /tmp /var/log /var directories and mount them to a separate file system partitions
2. What is the best way to perform this?
3. Things which i have explored along the way is:
4. Add a new ebs volume to the existing instance on top of the root volume and perform fdsik on the new disk and create a partition and mount it.

Which is the best way to do: TO Partition the root volume or to add a new ebs volume and partition it?

Comment: Have you attached a new EBS volume to the instance through the EBS console in AWS? If you run `sudo fdisk -l`, does it show the new volume?

Comment: Yes it does. I have added a new ebs volume on top of the default root volumne